# Selenium unable to identify div element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, python

I'm trying to access the div element by it's content (which is text) using the xpath, but it's not able to find the element.

I have a number of td items:

```
<tr role="listitem">
<td class="cellDark" height="20" align="left" style="WIDTH:52px;OVERFLOW:hidden;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;;white-space: nowrap;">
<div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;WIDTH:48px;" cellclipdiv="true" role="presentation">TRY</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr role="listitem">
<td class="cellDark" height="20" align="left" style="WIDTH:52px;OVERFLOW:hidden;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;;white-space: nowrap;">
<div style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;WIDTH:48px;" cellclipdiv="true" role="presentation">COL</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to click on the TRY div element. It actually appears in a dropdown (which doesn't have any unique identifiers in it - ID or class or anything). They change dynamically, so I have to rely on the text only.

I've tried using this approach to find the TRY div element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'TRY')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'TRY')]").click()
```

But this results into following error:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible
>   and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access an element which *hasn't been loaded yet*.

You need to first access the dropdown menu in order to activate the elements inside the dropdown list. After that the XPath you have mentioned will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'TRY')]").click()
```